# C++ wifstream: Incompatible type char const*, wchar_t const*

Tags: c++

I'm following a DirectX 3D model loading tutorial [here](http://www.braynzarsoft.net/index.php?p=D3D11OBJMODEL#still) and I'm testing small portions of the code as I go along. To load my .obj files I need to use a wide file stream, and the tutorial prompts that to initialise a new stream I need to pass in a wide string.

I have deviated a little from the tutorial as I wish to convert the demonstrated serial implementation into a neat OO package, however I am getting an `incompatible type char const* to wchar_t const*` error when I try to initialise my `file` variable for reading

How can I fix this problem?

```
class Stream {
private:
    std::wifstream file;
public:
    bool open_file(std::wstring &filename) {
        file = std::wifstream(filename.c_str());    // error thrown here.
    }
};
```

Calling the `open` function from main.

```
std::wstring filename = "test_read.txt";
if(d.open_file(filename))
{
    // Do read processing here
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How, in your mind, does a random forum post in a random forum entitled "beginner" written by a random person qualify as "the C++ documentation"?

Comment: Oh man, I didn't check that resource properly...

Comment: Right. You should have consulted the documentation (why does nobody do this any more? seriously >.<) _but_ at its heart this is a problem of the tutorial you're reading. So +0.6 from me rounded up to +1.

Comment: He does say at the bottom `fix the bugs` so I'm guessing thats one of the more deceptive ones to a C++ outcast like myself.  But yes, I'll admit, I need to make better use of the docs

Comment: You appear to be learning well. :)

Comment: It's scary coming from a Java background :P but is definitely a lot more fun, thanks again :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you are trying to *assign a stream*, and you cannot do that. Streams are not containers but *flows of data*. They therefore cannot be copied or assigned-to. Instead you may use the `open` member function of the stream object:

```
class Stream {
private:
    std::wifstream file;
public:
    bool open_file(std::wstring &filename) {
        file.open(filename.c_str());
    }
};
```

Then we return to the problem of the filename. The tutorial you are reading is *wrong*. 
[The following overloads are available for all `basic_ifstream` instantiations](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream/open):

```
void open( const char *filename,
           ios_base::openmode mode = ios_base::in );
void open( const std::string &filename,                                  
           ios_base::openmode mode = ios_base::in );
```

That is, regardless of the `CharT` of the stream, only honest-to-god `const char*` and `std::string` shall be accepted for the filename.

More than likely, the tutorial has made assumptions based on [non-standard extensions provided by Microsoft's standard library implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/70bb7saf.aspx), which adds overloads taking `const wchar_t*`. If you wish to write portable code, ignore these overloads.

Finally, you are not presently returning anything from `open_file`, which results in undefined behaviour.

Your corrected code shall look something like this:

```
class Stream {
private:
    std::wifstream file;
public:
    bool open_file(const std::string& filename) {
        file.open(filename);    // file.open(filename.c_str()) in C++03
        return file.is_open();
    }
};
```

Comment: Right that makes complete sense, thanks - I'll open a new question as what Im about to ask goes out of scope - but what I want to do is write functions for when a certain char is encountered. I.e. if I keep getting characters and encounter `f` I want to extract face information, therefore I have methods such as `get_float()`, which returns the next vertex normal - am I able to do that by accessing the global `file` stream or not?

Comment: @Alex Not really sure what you mean. I was with you until the last sentence.

Comment: Doh! Let me re-phrase, failing that look out for a new post in the next half hour.  Once I've opened a file I have a read method which keeps getting the next char.  In an obj file each line is prefixed by a char i.e. `f` for face `v` for vertex.  When I encounter an `f` a sequence like `4/5/8` will occur, I need to extract those integers one by one, ignoring the `/` characters.  Therefore in my main read loop, I want to abstract that extraction method so I don't bloat my code.  My question is, whilst in the while loop to read the file, can I access the current position outside method scope

Comment: @Alex: That's not really answerable in general terms. There are probably ways you can do it. It'll depend on precisely what the code looks like.

Comment: Right okay - maybe I'll post later if I can't figure it out, thanks for your time.

Comment: This post is quite old already, but I would have downvoted just for the "honest-to-god `const char *`, be it a ironic, because it was definitly a mistake in the standard library Microsoft managed to mitigate at that time, obviously in a non standard way. It was just not possible to manage utf16 encoded filenames at that time unless with Microsoft library...a peanut.

Comment: @Heyji Sorry, I did not understand your comment. Can you explain the problem with this answer?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, there should have been an open member function in the wifstream class with a wstring filename as first argument (or wchar_t instead of char only). Calling char and string "honest-to-god" sounds retrograde and silently ignores all the work made to democratize the use of other encodings than ASCII.

Comment: @Heyji I think you misunderstand the idiom "honest-to-god" but hey that's okay!

Comment: @Heyji By the way, you're not quite correct either. A `char*` or `std::string` can carry UTF-8 or, really, strings in _any encoding_. It's Microsoft who forced everybody to use one single encoding (UCS-2, a bit like UTF-16) with a particular character width. Not so democratic.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, you may want to read about encodings, especially about their history. I suggest you start with this https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/

Comment: @Heyji Thank you, but I am quite familiar with how text encoding works. If you would like to make a specific counter-argument then by all means do so.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit As non native English speaker, I certainly miss part of the meaning of "honest-to-god". Though I think I get enough of it to argue that calling `char` honest-to-god is a misrepresentation of how it shall be considered, today. Saying it would have deserved a downvote was provocative and wrong, I indeed did not downvote, and it was not the point and your answer (beside this word) addressed the point correctly. I insist, read about HISTORY of encodings. I know you know how it works.

Comment: @Heyji: I'm familiar with the history, too. Here, by "honest-to-god" I just meant "basic, simple, straightforward, original, without excess undue complication"; the history of encodings is completely irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

`std::wifstream` takes a `const char*` in its constructor.  You cannot pass it the `c_str` from a `wstring` as a `wstring` returns an `const charT*`.  These types are incompatible.